# I am creating a validation rule. requirement is when we select status=junk any below field cant be blank

Tags: validation-rule

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Junk"),
    OR(ISBLANK( Phone ), 
    OR(ISBLANK ( Email ), 
    OR(ISBLANK( Description ), 
    OR(ISBLANK(  Company  )
)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please also add exactly what is (or is not) happening with this code: Are you getting an error? (If so, include *exact* error text.) Are there no errors but it is giving you unexpected results? (If so, detail those results.) Are there no errors and you cannot tell if anything is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The OR condition needs to have all the blank checks together. If anyone of the fields *Phone*, *Email*, *Description* and *Company* is blank, the OR condition will be true.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Junk"), 
    OR( 
        ISBLANK( Phone ), 
        ISBLANK ( Email ), 
        ISBLANK( Description ), 
        ISBLANK( Company )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one validation for each of those fields, you will need to add an exception to all of them otherwise, they will be triggered.

"AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Junk")), THAT_FIELD_VALIDATION)"